# Помогите с javascript

Tags: php, javascript

здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста реализовать этот код

```
<?php if ($product['attribute_groups']) { 
    foreach ($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) { 
        foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
            <p><b><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></b>: <?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></p>
  <?php } 
    }
} ?>
```

на javascript! спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

типо такого

```
if(typeof product['attribute_groups'] != undefined)
{
    var text = "";
    for(key in product['attribute_groups'])
    {
        data = product['attribute_groups'][key];
        for(k in data['attribute'])
        {
             text += "<p><b>"+ data[k]['name'] +"</b>:"+ $data[k]['text'] +"</p>";
        }
    }
    document.write(text);
}
```

Comment: преогромное спасибо, очень помогли!!!!